# Can't connect to MySql server(error)

Tags: php, mysql

I want to create a database in MySql, but I'm having a hard time connecting to it.  This is what I've done.

In cmd as administrator, I've located the bin folder and typed the command: mysql -u root -p -h localhost.  It prompted me with a password, is this my computer password for entry to the user? Attempted that, same message as the title says.  I saw on videos that people didn't have a password, so they just pressed enter.  I just pressed enter, same result as title.  So, I downloaded MySql Workbench 6.3 and went through a tutorial on youtube, I pressed the 'plus' button and tried to configure the server with port 3306 on 127.0.0.1, it couldnt connect to the server.

When I start the Xaamp control panel, apache server will run but when I try to start  the mySQL server, it gives me a prompt with yes or no, I press yes and then nothing happens.

I've typed 'run' into the start bar.  I then typed 'services.msc' and found mysql, it was not running, I pressed start on top left, it then prompted me with a message saying it was stopped because it wasnt being used.

What do i do?  How do I get the server to start?  what is my password?

Comment: If it is the default configuration the password would be nothing. If you are running mysql on linux you could do `service mysql start` depending on the version. I don't see the PHP relation here.

Comment: try running this service as administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your CLI and type the following:

```
RUNAS /user:<your_username>\administrator /SAFECRED cmd.exe
```

Then a new instance of CMD will pop up using your rights. Type then this:

```
NET START mysql
```

If it's still not working, then it means your service is disabled. Open your XAMPP, check the box on the left in the line where MySQL is then close it. After that, retry the steps above.

Once the service has started, type this to run and connect:

```
mysql -u root
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using windows (since you said cmd) and the proper command for getting into the CLI tool from the bin directory is
    **mysql.exe -u yourusername -p**   and then you wil be prompted to enter your password.